# Using form_for to create two records at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have two different models called Infraction and Lock. These belong to my User model, and a User `has_one` Lock and `many` Infractions.

Administrators have the ability to create Locks on Users, and also give them Infractions, however for serious offences it would be necessary to give an Infraction and simultaneously put a Lock on the User.

To save admins from having to click on multiple forms, I was thinking that I could roll everything into one form: building an Infraction and a Lock on the same User at the same time, but I'm not sure how to do it. I was thinking of using a form_for block to do it, before I realized it can only take one object.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out fields_for helper, and accepts_nested_attributes_for. The combination of the two will do what you need.

Example:

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  ...
  <%= person_form.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
    ...
    Delete: <%= address_fields.check_box :_destroy %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And your person class would be something like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Comment: Would this work if both `Infraction` and `Lock` belonged to `User`? I dont want to update `User` while adding locks or infractions

Comment: You don't have to update any attributes on the user object; just use it to build the form you need and let it update what it needs to in your associated objects. And, you shouldn't have to change the association type between User and Lock; the has_one should be ok. What's the inverse relationship from Lock to User specified as?

Comment: yeah, so I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work. Have you tried it yet?